# unable to generate report for task reportScoverage using Scoverage plugin for gradle

Tags: gradle, scoverage

Have integrated scoverare plugin of gradle for scala project and am able to run all the tasks from command line.

the reportScoverage task runs but it skips saying no output type defined.

I tried following

reportScoverage {

coverageOutputHTML = true
}

but it failed with error that no such property "coverageOutputHTML" defined

Scoverage plugin version : 1.1.0

can someone let me know or point to tutorial on how to define it.